# Are all Givens rotations linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analytic-geometry, rotations, projection-matrices

I've read that Givens rotations are linear transformations, but as we know linear transformations preserve the length of the vector transformed. However when I tried this with a 3 dimensional Givens rotation matrix G(1,2,45°) it seems that the length of the vector transformed changes, and when putting in it into a 3d grapher it the transformation resambles a plan projection.

Is that normal?

Comment: Linear transformations do not necessarily preserve vector length

Comment: Where did you read that linear transformations preserve vector length? Consider the linear map $\vec v\mapsto 2\vec v$ which doubles vector length. Are you perhaps confusing linear transformations with rigid transformation?

Comment: *Orthogonal* transformations preserve vector length (and angles)

Comment: ${\bf x} \to 2 {\bf x}$ is linear, but of course does not generally preserve length.

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry linear transformation don't preserve vector's length all the time. But does givens rotation preserve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome here Saad!

First point: linear transformations do not necessarily preserve the length. Take for example the map $A(x,y,z) = (3x,3y,3z)$: the length of the result is three times the original length!

Second point: luckily, rotations do preserve the length, so there should be something wrong with your matrix $G(1, 2, 45°) $ . How is it defined? If it is meant to be the rotation around the z-axis of 45°, it should be

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\
- \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: OP is talking about Givens' rotation used in numerical linear algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation)

Comment: It seems like I guessed the form by chance XD

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Givens rotations are still rotations, you just have more dimensions and a matrix that is the identity except on two dimensions.

Comment: Hello Andrea, the thing with Givens rotations is that they're just normal rotations but instead of rotating around an axis, the vector rotates around a plane (basically two vectors at the same time). But as said, normally Givens rotations do preserve the length of the transform vector but in my example it doesn't seem to fit. I'm just wondering where I went wrong? Thanks

Comment: In the three dimensional case when you rotate the plane xy, this is actually a rotation *around* z axis, meaning that the latter is fixed. Write explicitly the matrix you are using and we will see where you are wrong.